# vertica install failing with ssh error

Tags: database, automation, administration, vertica

I was trying to install vertica using `/opt/vertica/sbin/install_vertica` script and following command `/opt/vertica/sbin/install_vertica -s vertica001,vertica002,vertica003 -r /root/packages/vertica-6.0.1-7.x86_64.RHEL5.rpm`

I was getting following error

```
Vertica Analytic Database 6.0.1-7 Installation Tool
Starting installation tasks...
Getting system information for cluster (this may take a while)....
'failed to login to 172.16.10.212: EOF ERROR: Could not login with SSH. Here is what SSH said:  (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).\r\r\n'

Updating Nodes that are UP

'failed to login to 172.16.10.18: EOF ERROR: Could not login with SSH. Here is what SSH said:  (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).\r\r\n'

Updating Nodes that are UP

Removing 172.16.10.212,172.16.10.18 from hosts list
backing up admintools.conf on 172.16.10.52
Info: the package 'pstack' is useful during troubleshooting. Vertica recommends this package is installed.
Checking/fixing OS parameters.....

Error: No JSON object could be decoded
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/vertica/bin/verticaInstall.py", line 1187, in <module>
if not SSH.check_min_free_kbytes(installerSSH, fix=True):
File "/opt/vertica/oss/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vertica/network/SSH.py", line 2388, in check_min_free_kbytes
data =json.loads( ''.join(res[host][1]))
File "/opt/vertica/oss/python/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 310, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/opt/vertica/oss/python/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 346, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/opt/vertica/oss/python/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I have setup passwordless ssh for dbadmin also it has sudo access.

Do I need to have passwordless ssh for root user here ? what I am missing here ?

Comment: test if root password-less is available, or run the install_vertica  as root !

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to have passwordless ssh for root user here ? what I am missing here ?

Yes. The installer runs on the nodes specified in the host parameter. If SSH is not set up between the nodes, how else is the installer supposed to complete the process? See [Configuring the Network](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/InstallationGuide/BeforeYouInstall/ConfiguringTheNetwork.htm) and how to [Enable Secure Shell (SSH) Logins](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/InstallationGuide/TroubleshootingTheInstall/EnableSecureShellSSHLogins.htm) in the doc.

**Q:** Why are you installing Vertica 6.0? The latest release is 7.2

Comment: this exercise is to test vertica upgrade from 6.0.1 to 7.2

Comment: @roy you're aware of the upgrade path?

Comment: Yes I was going to upgrade from 6.0.1 > 6.1 > 7.1 > 7.2. Is that correct ?